# values are scrambled when we call a RFC method in .NET with SAP .NET Connector 2.0

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector

With .NET SAP Connector 2.0 we invoke a RFC Method.

When we pass only one character in the parameters, the values are stored in the SAP system and readable when we query the table in the SAP system.
When we pass only more then one character in the parameters, the values are stored in the SAP system and **not** readable when we query the table in the SAP system.

We checked the function and parameter and the structure of the table in the SAP system.

The support on the SAP side is none.

```
*RfcMethod(AbapName = "Z_SD_UPDATE_OPC_TAB" )]
    public string Z_SD_UPDATE_OPC_TAB(
       [RfcParameter(AbapName = "WERKS", RfcType = RFCTYPE.RFCTYPE_STRING , Optional = false, Direction = RFCINOUT.IN, Length = 4)]  string plant)*
{

SAPInvoke("Z_SD_UPDATE_OPC_TAB", new object[]
{
  plant
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if Unicode Encoding is the same in SAP and the .NET connector.  As well as on the .NET side.

Comment: Sorry, I don't kow. Have you asked that as a question? There's bound to be someone that's more familiar with it.

Comment: It's pretty vague, I know - Unicode was just the only thing that came to mind that may actually give you an unscrambled output if you use only one character.